# How to make a hyperlink through GridView column value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

[image]

I want here that user can see the answer under the question by selecting its `heading`. The question should be a hyperlink to redirect me on the page `Answer.aspx`. I mean to say that when user take cursor over the `How to do this?` it should redirect the user to the desired page. How can I do that?

here is the code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
       DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="100%" BorderStyle="None">
       <Columns>  
     <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionHEAD" HeaderText="Question"
                                        SortExpression="QuestionHEAD" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="white" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Brown"/>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Problem" HeaderText="Problem" 
                                        SortExpression="Problem" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="white" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Brown" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Forum" HeaderText="Forum" SortExpression="Forum" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="white" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Brown"/>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Asked By" 
                                        SortExpression="Username" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="white" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Brown" />
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connectionstring %>" 
                                SelectCommand="SELECT [QuestionHEAD], [Problem], [Forum], [Username] FROM [Question]">
                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Please post your current `GridView` markup/codeing

Comment: Are you saying that you want the `Question` column to contain links?

Comment: @james johnson yes I want to do that. As on SO we click on the question and it redirect us for answer's that the same way I want. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `HyperLinkField` for this:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/somepage.aspx?a={0}&b={1}" DataNavigateUrlFields="Column1, Column2" />
```

Comment: What are the `a` and `b` is here for. And is it setting the both columns to hyperlink?

Comment: It's just an example that demonstrates how you can incorporate information from the datasource into your URL. In your case, you'd probably want to pass the `QuestionID` or something.

Comment: There is no question ID how can I generate them through uniqueIdentifier?

Comment: You don't have a primary key on the table, or anything to uniquely identify each question?

Comment: No it doesn't have because I want to use Internal DB and there is no option to use Identity.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Eval("id") should be the question id and Eval("Question") should be the question field in your database


 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Question" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="Answers.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("id")%>"> <%#Eval("Question")%></a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: There is no question ID how can I generate them through uniqueIdentifier?

Comment: how is your database table look like, dosen't it have a primary key?

Comment: No it doesn't have because I want to use Internal DB and there is no option to use Identity. I was about to ask question for that.